# CocoaPods localization files getting over written

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, podspec

In my own Pod, I provide some Localization String files that the users can alter according to their needs. But when they run 'pod update', the files get overwritten and the changes are lost. I don't want to force the user to backup the files.

Is there any way to fix this? Any way run a script before 'pod update' runs?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are providing these files to the user to alter as per their needs. You should instead have a hook to let them add their files to your pod. When you do a `pod update`, you are essentially deleting and re-downloading your project's files in the `Pods/` directory if a new version of your Pod is available. That's why your localization files are getting deleted.

You can fix this by having a [prepare_command](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#prepare_command) that copies these files outside the `Pods/` folder and then re-adds them to the project, or simply have the users add these files in separately.